# slimScroll javascript to left and right not up and down

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, slimscroll

I nedd a scroll but not to up and down I need to left and right not vertical, I need horizontal, I use slimScroll.js, can I do that, I can creata a scroll to up and down with this library, how can I create to left and right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it stands no. Lots of requests on the homepage though so hopefully that will be a future release.