# Slimscroll with sortable makes sortable contents hide when dragged to ather containers

Tags: jquery, css, slimscroll

How to Restrict slimscroll to scroll in y-axis only?

I found answer in [stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291604/slimscroll-javascript-to-left-and-right-not-up-and-down)

It says no. Is there any other fix for it?

The problem is it appends overflow hidden to the div... It makes my sortable divs bad. While moving one sortable element from one container to other it is hidden.

Comment: No. till now it will support only vertical scroll.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai The problem is it appends overflow hidden to the div... It makes my sortable divs bad. While moving one sortable element from one container to other it is hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $('.scrollable-content').slimScroll({
        height: '90vh'
    });
```

Then for fix I added this

```
    $('.slimScrollDiv').css('overflow', '');
```

where .slimScrollDiv is the class produced by slimscroll.
Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fix it by modifying the line
    `overflow: 'visible'`
for the parent, directly in jquery.slimscroll.js.
Here is the full code section:

```
// wrap content
var wrapper = $(divS)
.addClass(o.wrapperClass)
.css({
position: 'relative',
overflow: 'visible', // --- !!! changed from hidden
width: o.width,
height: o.height
});
```

IMHO i believe this is a bug so I just fix it in source code. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use below style on the container on which you are applying  `.slimscroll({ config })`

**JS**

```
$('#slimtest1').slimScroll({
    height: '200px'
});
```

**CSS**

```
#slimtest1{
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: u mean to say that horizontal scroll is also coming even if overflow is hidden?